# Perl Catalyst: Create and force download PDF

Tags: perl, pdf, download, catalyst

I have a Controller with Action('RenderView') method that creates a PDF on-the-fly using PDF::API2.

I don't want to save the PDF, rather, I would like to force a download dialog. Something like this pseudo-code:

```
... create pdf on-the-fly ...
$pdf->saveas($fullPathToFilename); # is there a way to avoid this?
binmode STDOUT;
$c->res->content_type('application/pdf');
$c->res->header( 'Content-Disposition', qq[attachment;filename='$shortFilename'] );
$c->res->header( 'someOtherHeaders' );
... here, stream binary content to client ?? ...
return $self->status_ok( $c, entity => 'PDF' );
```

I suppose I could test repeatedly for the existence of the file a created and serve it when it's saved and discovered. That seems very kludgie to me.

Anyone have a better solution?

Thanks,
Noah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::API2):

```
$string = $pdf->stringify();
```

Return the document as a string and remove the object structure from memory.